# How to count after using group by in SQL

Tags: sql

I have a sample dataset with Customer set like this

| Name | Shop | Amount | Category |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Tom | RR | 50 | Apparel |
| Tom | JJ | 100 | Grocery |
| Tom | RR | 20 | Apparel |

I wanted to group table by `customer_Name, Shop` but also the total transaction `count`.

My SQL query look like

```
SELECT
Name, Shop, SUM(Amount),Category, Count(*) AS Num_of_Txn 
FROM Table
GROUP BY
Name, Shop, Category
```

The Result i get is like

| Name | Shop | Amount | Category | Num_of_Txn |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| TOM | RR | 70 | Apparel | 2 |
| TOM | JJ | 100 | Grocery | 1 |

But i wanted `Num_of Txn` as 3 based on the distinct customer transaction for an customer. How should i proceed? I'm learner and looking for help in the logic/code.

Comment: you have 3 rows and you're grouping them into 2 rows with different Shop/Category. Which of your two rows do you think should show *3* as the count? Please show the results you expect to see.

Comment: From the sounds of it you need to remove your category from the group.

Comment: I need distinct purchase by customers as number of purchases as txn. In this case, there are 3 unique purchases made, so i need 3 as answer. There are numerous transactions so i wanted them to group to reduce the run time of query in tableau

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the record, a window function over the count() aggregate would do what you ask.
But with `PARTITION BY name`:

```sql
SELECT name, shop, sum(amount) AS amount, category
     , sum(count(*)) OVER (PARTITION BY name) AS num_of_txn 
FROM   tbl
GROUP  BY name, shop, category;
```

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/wXHF1qt9)

Answer (score 0):

I suppose that COUNT(*) is invalid for solution, because of 3 rows it becomes 2 rows.
Inner query is needed.
As row number numerates each row 1,2,3 and so on.
To last row, number 3 is assigned 3.

```
SELECT X.Name, X.Shop, X.Category, SUM(Amount), Category, MAX(RN) AS TotalTXCount
    FROM
    (
      SELECT Name, Shop, 
             Amount, Category,
             ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY Name) AS RN
      FROM Customers
    ) AS X
    GROUP BY Name, Shop, Category
```

Comment: Hi, Thanks for helping. I tried this. But this doesnt give the desired result. There are 'n' number of customers. I need number of distinct purchases by each customer as "TotalTxnCount". But this query accumulates txncount by row number for every customer and gives results as 2,4,6,7 which is not the desired result

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Hi I finally found a solution. I created two tables. One Table as Purchase with Customer_Name and Num_of_Txn and another table as Customer by Customer_Name, Shop,Sum(Amount),Product, Purchase.Num_of_txn I joined two table by customer_name. That worked as it joined Num_of_txn from Purchase Table with Customer Table based on Customer_Name.

Thanks for all those who helped me.

Answer (score 0):

use `SUM() Over()` Built in  function to get sum of Count all Records as follows your Code Modified as Follows

```
SELECT
 Name, Shop, SUM(Amount),Category, Sum(Count(*)) over() AS Num_of_Txn 
 FROM Table
GROUP BY
Name, Shop, Category
```

### Result will be

| Name | Shop | Amount | Category | Num_of_Txn |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| TOM | RR | 70 | Apparel | 3 |
| TOM | JJ | 100 | Grocery | 3 |

Comment: Thank you. Use of Sum(Count (*) over(partition by Customer_name) function helped me.